# How to make a module prerequisite in drupal

Tags: 7

How should i make a module that is prerequisite for an existing module.

For example:

Step 1 : There is comment module in core itself.

Step 2 : In my module i am doing some **form alter which affects comment module**. Consider my module name as  comment_test.

Step 3 : **While enabling comment module my custom module that is comment_test should be as required module.**

Step 4 : How can this be done?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

using below format in .info file of the module.

```
dependencies[] = D1
dependencies[] = D2
```

I the above lines, D1 & D2 represent the names of the modules you module depend on.

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked into how Drupal manages module files? You define a module's dependencies in the .info file. [Here is the documentation on drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/542202).

Answer (score 1):

When you are enabling a module in Drupal, the module dependencies are checked from the module .info file, and you will have to enable all dependencies to enable you module.

Lets say you have two modules : foo & bar, and that foo requires bar.
If you add: dependencies[] = "bar" in the foo's .info file, you will need to enable bar in order to enable foo.

In your case if you are working with the core comment module, you could edit the comment module .info file. But usually when you set a dependency, it means that the module needs the dependency to run properly. So unless you have modified the core comment module, it should not need another module to run properly. If you have modified the core module, you should know that for many reasons its is not advised to do so. The first reason is that you will not be able to update the core modules. The good way to do it is to create another module alter the comment module behavior.

The logic should be :

If i only need the comment module, i can enable it without having to enable other modules.

If i need the comment_test module, i can enable it, but it will require the comment module as it is a dependency.

This is why you cannot set your module as a prerequisite to a core module without creating another module that would extend Drupal with such behavior or by modifying the .info file in the core module.